# Creating a table from topic with value of String type in KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How can one create a table from a topic which contains value of type String?

We have some topics that contains rdf data embedded inside strings, in a sense it is just a string value. Based on the KSQLDB documentation, we need to use value_format='KAFKA' with WRAP_SINGLE_VALUE=false given that it is an anonymous value.

```
CREATE SOURCE Table source_table_proxy (
    key VARCHAR primary KEY,
    value VARCHAR
) WITH (
    KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA',
    VALUE_FORMAT='KAFKA', 
    WRAP_SINGLE_VALUE=false,
    kafka_topic = 'topic'
);
```

This is the topic info:

```
Key Type: STRING
Value Type: STRING
Topic Info
Partitions: 12
Replication: 1
```

Weirdly we get the following error:

```
The 'KAFKA' format only supports a single field. Got: [`VALUE` STRING, `ROWPARTITION` INTEGER, `ROWOFFSET` BIGINT]
```

Is there any workaround this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you need `KAFKA` format.

The `JSON` format will work for plain (primitive) strings as well

> supports reading and writing top-level primitives, arrays and maps.
>
> For example, given a SQL statement with only a single field in the value schema and the `WRAP_SINGLE_VALUE` property set to false:
>
> `CREATE STREAM x (ID BIGINT) WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', WRAP_SINGLE_VALUE=false, ...);`
>
> And a JSON value of:
>
> ```
> 10
> ```
>
> ksqlDB can deserialize the values into the ID field of the stream

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/serialization/#top-level-primitives-arrays-and-maps